# Apache2 500 Internal Server Error

Tags: php, apache, web-services, ubuntu, apache2

I´ve a problem with my apache2. I can´t access the mydomain.com. I don´t know what i done wrong.In my apache2/sites-enabled/000-default i configured a VHost for seafile. But i think its no problem with seafile because i can´t acces a page on the server.
Here is my **/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default**:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride None
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log

    # Possible values include: debug, info, notice, warn, error, crit,
    # alert, emerg.
    LogLevel warn

    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

Alias /doc/ "/usr/share/doc/"
<Directory "/usr/share/doc/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.0/255.0.0.0 ::1/128
</Directory>

</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName http://vm371.rz.uos.de
DocumentRoot /var/www
Alias /media  /home/user/mariuslange/mariuscloud/seafile-server-3.0.3/seahub/media

RewriteEngine On

<Location /media>
Require all granted
</Location>

#
# seafile httpserver
#
ProxyPass /seafhttp http://127.0.0.1:8082
ProxyPassReverse /seafhttp http://127.0.0.1:8082
RewriteRule ^/seafhttp - [QSA,L]

#
# seahub
#
RewriteRule ^/(media.*)$ /$1 [QSA,L,PT]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /seahub.fcgi$1 [QSA,L,E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</VirtualHost>
```

Here are my debug log files from **/var/log/apache2/error.log**(2 page views)

```
    [Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [error] [client 24.134.128.158] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 24.134.128.158] r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /
[Sun May 18 14:07:21 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 24.134.128.158] Zlib: Compressed 619 to 384 : URL /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [error] [client 24.134.128.158] Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3112): [client 24.134.128.158] r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected  from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /index.php
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [debug] core.c(3118): [client 24.134.128.158] redirected from r->uri = /phpmyadmin
[Sun May 18 14:17:23 2014] [debug] mod_deflate.c(615): [client 24.134.128.158] Zlib: Compressed 619 to 384 : URL /index.php
```

Best regards!